# Problem with CMake and rosserial_arduino

Tags: arduino, macos-snowleopard, rosserial, osx, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

When I'm trying to go through this tutorial in my OS X 10.6:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/CMake

I have the ARDUINO_SDK_PATH-NOTFOUND problem mentioned, so I add
set(ARDUINO_SDK_PATH <path_to_arduino_installation>)
into my CMakeLists.txt. Here is the whole CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
rosbuild_find_ros_package(rosserial_arduino)
set(ARDUINO_SDK_PATH /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java)
include(${rosserial_arduino_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake_scripts/rosserial.cmake)
set(FIRMWARE_NAME chatter)
set(${FIRMWARE_NAME}_BOARD uno)         # Arduino Target board
set(${FIRMWARE_NAME}_SRCS src/chatter.cpp )
set(${FIRMWARE_NAME}_PORT /dev/tty.usbmodem411)            # Serial upload port
generate_ros_firmware(${FIRMWARE_NAME})
```

But when I'm try to compile it, I have got the following error:

```
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/uno_CORE.dir/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp.o
make[3]: avr-g++: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/uno_CORE.dir/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/uno_CORE.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/chatter.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [chatter] Error 2
```

I know it cannot find avr-g++, but I have already point out the ARDUINO_SDK_PATH, so I think something is missing. I have no problem when I use Arduino IDE to do compile the same code. Do you guys know how to solve this problem? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12030/problem-with-cmake-and-rosserial_arduino/) by [cnhzcy14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1411/cnhzcy14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Still have problem. I tried the tutorial and CMake scripts from original arduino_cmake:
[https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake](http://https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake)

That works on my OS X. So I tried to look into these scripts. In original top CMakeLists.txt, there are two lines:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules)  # CMake module search path
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/toolchains/Arduino.cmake) # Arduino Toolchain
```

But in rosserial.cmake in rosserial_arduino package, these two lines become:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH    ${rosserial_arduino_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake_scripts/modules)  # CMake module search path
include(${rosserial_arduino_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake_scripts/toolchains/Arduino.cmake) # Arduino Toolchain
```

So I changed them into

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH    ${rosserial_arduino_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake_scripts/modules)  # CMake module search path
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${rosserial_arduino_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake_scripts/toolchains/Arduino.cmake) # Arduino Toolchain
```

Now I have following error:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-mmcu=atmega328p"
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/uno_CORE.dir/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/uno_CORE.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm not a CMake guy, so is there anyone can help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

BTW the arduino installation path in OS X is

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java
```

---

Originally posted by [cnhzcy14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1411/cnhzcy14/) with karma: 58 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install avr-gcc and friends. Under Ubuntu, you can install everything as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install avr-libc avrdude
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-11-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cnhzcy14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1411/cnhzcy14/) on 2011-11-22**:
It will work on Ubuntu. But I'm using OS X. I have avr-libc avrdude installed by macports, but still have errors when compiling.